# Testing Grape with Minitest - What class to inherit from?

Tags: ruby, minitest, ruby-grape, grape-api

My rails application is using minitest. It's unclear to me what class I should be inheriting for my test. I was thinking ActionController::TestCase but that doesn't seem right because it isn't attached to a rails controller. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Can't use `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` because it doesn't include anything to the test the individual api end points.

Comment: I took 30 seconds to google "minitest" and it looks like the answer should be `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`?

Comment: Sorry if I sounded condescending to you, I didn't mean to be. What do you mean by your "api end points"?

Comment: Grape is a library for Ruby to create HTTP APIs. You can integrate it into rails to a certain extent. When you're writing tests, you'll need to use GET, POST on your HTTP endpoints. ActionController::TestCase gives you a get method to call on a controller and action but that wouldn't work in this case. I'm looking for what to inherit from so I can get a get/post method and any other HTTP helpers.

Comment: Maybe try inheriting from `Minitest::Unit::TestCase` and `include`ing `ActiveSupport::TestCase::Behavior::ClassMethods` then?

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I ended up using `Rack::Test::Methods` since ActiveSupport doesn't include any HTTP Methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from a specific minitest class, I just included test helpers from Rack.

```
class V0::YourAPI < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rails.application
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` class

For example:

```
class ApiRequestTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
 test "sample response" do
  get "/api/v1/sample_request"
  assert_equal response.success?, true
  assert_equal response.code, 200
 end
end
```